# Graph on Chronosphere (Grafana) using Prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

need your help.
I have a requirement where I need to plot my graph something like below but not able to plot it.
[image: Sample Graph]

**I m getting prometheus metrics in this form using Gauge**

```
kafka_delta_demo{cost_origin="databricks", environment="production", exported_environment="dev", instance="prom-aggregation-gateway-databricks", job="databricks", qp_batch_id="13221", qp_duration_sec="69.45", qp_input_rows_per_second="472", qp_num_input_rows="40045", qp_processed_rows_per_second="576", service="databricks"}
kafka_delta_demo{cost_origin="databricks", environment="production", exported_environment="dev", instance="prom-aggregation-gateway-databricks", job="databricks", qp_batch_id="13222", qp_duration_sec="74.26", qp_input_rows_per_second="478", qp_num_input_rows="33229", qp_processed_rows_per_second="447", service="databricks"}
```

**X-axis** --> batch_id (basically minutes incremented by 1)

**Graph** --> Should show number of rows processed(qp_processed_rows_per_second) for duration(qp_duration_sec) for each batch.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I can change metrics type. Also can divide into different metrics types if required.